# Set a ListView unsrollable in javaFx

Tags: javafx

I would like to know how could I make a list view unscrollabe (in JavaFx). I can't find any setter or getter to do that. I'am looking for something like this :

```
myListView.setScrollable(false);
```

If somebody can help me to do that I'll be glad :).

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this (no vbar policy like `ScrollPane` it had)

Try this:

```
.list-view .virtual-flow .scroll-bar:vertical {
    visibility: false;
}
```

This doesn't realy solve your problem. The user can't click on the thumb, increment and decrement button, can't scroll with the scroll wheel but can select an item and press up or down arrow keys on the keyboard.

Comment: In fact I use touch modality. My scrollbar is already hidden. I want to desactivate scrolling because I already used it to drag and drop the elements of the list.